# Creating Log In Elements with Variables for websocketdata

Tags: html, facebook, authentication, frontend

I'm trying to refine the log-in process from my front end.  Right now, I have it set so the "login" button just utilizes generic data "testuser."  For both username and password.

What I'd like is for the fields I have to be filled in by a user, and upon clicking the button, that user data used instead of "testuser."

```
          <label for="username">User Name</label><input id="username"/>
          <var username = username>
          <label for="password">Password</label><input id="password"/>
          <var password = password>




          <button onClick='gamesparks.registrationRequest("testuser", "testuser", "testuser", registerResponse)'>Register</button>
            <button onClick='gamesparks.authenticationRequest("testuser", "testuser", loginResponse)'>Login</button>
```

My code is in my header.php file and is easy for me to understand.  But I'm not sure how to create a log in field that will submit user data!

To throw a curve ball at everyone, I have a facebook login API already set up.  That code is included as part of a widget in wordpress and looks like this:

```
    <?php do_action('facebook_login_button');?>

[fbl_login_button redirect="" hide_if_logged=""]

    <!-- Here is my FB code-->
<head>
    <body>
    <script>
    // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into your app or we are unable to tell.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '{193547157855095}',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

</body>

<script>
var finished_rendering = function() {
console.log("finished rendering plugins");
var spinner = document.getElementById("spinner");
spinner.removeAttribute("style");
spinner.removeChild(spinner.childNodes[0]);
}
FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', finished_rendering);
</script>
<div id="spinner"
    style="
        background: #4267b2;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: white;
        height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 250px;">
    Loading
    <div
    class="fb-login-button"
    data-max-rows="1"
    data-size="large"
    data-button-type="continue_with"
    ></div>
</div>
}

<!--End of FB code-->
```

So there it is.  A big challenge.  I want to capture the login information from the facebook button.  Even just a username would be fine...and submit that into my button for loggin in.  HELP!

Comment: _“I want to capture the login information from the facebook button”_ - no, stay the hell away from that. A user’s Facebook login credentials are never any of your business. Your app would be in violation of Facebook’s policy if you even tried. You should use the user id to get from the API to identify the user in your system, not any other data.

Comment: That is what I mean!  I don't want anyone's password!  I just want their user id...or...screw it.  Even a randomly assigned user ID number.  I just have to have something that is uniquely theirs.  Facebook is just convenient for people.  All of their log in stuff is encrypted on my end anyway, when I use the API.

Comment: Well then implement Facebook Login, and you get a unique, app-scoped user id for everyone who logs in using it. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/